# does NetLogo's ask-with ensure lazy evaluation?

Tags: netlogo

How equivalent are the following two lines of code?

```
ask agentset [if (attr > 0) [dosomething]]

ask agentset with [attr > 0] [dosomething]
```

Are there any expected (and explainable) differences
in speed or the use of memory?
In particular, does the use of `with` in the second
case lead to the creation of a temporary agentset,
or does the `ask ... with` combination ensure
lazy evaluation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just to expand on what Nicolas said:

ask-with is *intentionally* not lazy. Consider code where the agents are modifying the attribute of other agents that determines whether or not they should be asked, so to speak:

```
to go
  ask patches with [ pcolor = red ] [
    ask neighbors4 [ set pcolor red ]
  ]
  tick
end
```

Because `with` creates a temporary agentset, which agents are asked is not changed mid-ask. This causes the red region to grow evenly as `go` is called repeatedly:

[image]

Now, consider it with `if` instead.

```
to go
  ask patches [ 
    if pcolor = red [
      ask neighbors4 [ set color red ]
    ]
  ]
  tick
end
```

Because patches that have not been asked yet might have have their color changed to red, the red region grows unevenly:

[image]

Thus, ask-with actually has different behavior then ask-if, and so cannot be optimized to it. That said, as Nicolas mentioned, some similar optimizations are done.

Answer (score 0):

(Disclaimer: my familiarity with the compiler is very superficial, so I might be missing something.)

A (possibly outdated) list of the optimizations performed by the NetLogo compiler is available here:

https://github.com/NetLogo/NetLogo/wiki/Compiler-architecture#optimizer

The actual code for those (in NetLogo 6.0) is here:

https://github.com/NetLogo/NetLogo/blob/bd3da2bf5495674ce5690cbb2992de4036c9db03/netlogo-core/src/main/compile/middle/optimize/package.scala

As far as I can tell, there is no optimization for `ask ... with`. It means that `ask ... with` *does* create an intermediate agentset and, as such, probably requires more memory and time than `ask ... [ if ... ]`.

<s>Which one you should use probably depends on where you stand on the efficiency/readability trade-off. (I personally find `ask ... with` more readable.)</s>

Would it be a good idea to optimize `ask ... with`? In my opinion, absolutely. That being said, there might have been a technical reason not to do it at the time the compiler was written. I just don't know about it.

There is, indeed, a very good reason why `ask ... with` is not optimized. And there are behavioral differences between the two versions; it's not just a matter of readability vs. efficiency. See Bryan's answer.

Comment: This is very much intentional; see Bryan's answer.